# JavaScript Regex to match any words within nested square brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a way to use regex to make text italic inside of square `[]` brackets, inclusive of nested square brackets, but not the brackets themselves.  So far the best I've come up with is:

```
text = text.replace(/(\[+)([^\[\]]+)(]+)/g, '$1<span style="font-style: italic;">$2</span>$3');
```

however that fails in the case of nested brackets, something like:

```
[test1] test2 ([[readonly ][optionality ][argumentType ]argumentName[ = defaultValue]]...) [test3] test4
```

Should parse to:

[*test1*] test2 ([[*readonly* ][*optionality* ][*argumentType* ]*argumentName*[ *= defaultValue*]]...) [*test3*] test4

But instead the above regex produces:

[*test1*] test2 ([[*readonly* ][*optionality* ][*argumentType* ]argumentName[ *= defaultValue*]]...) [*test3*] test4

(with the text `argumentName` normal instead of italics)

Comment: You can't solve this using (only) regexes, you need to write a parser.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/acdcjunior/cfee862d1618e693bdc6 this one *is* a parser.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to match each bracket group and replace each word within that group inside of the replace callback:

```
string.replace(/(\[(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]]*)*\])/g, function (match) {
  return match.replace(/(\w+)/g, '*$1*');
});
```

Example Snippet:

```js
var string = "[test1] test2 ([[readonly ][optionality ][argumentType ]argumentName[ = defaultValue]]...) [test3] test4";

var result = string.replace(/(\[(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]]*)*\])/g, function (match) {
  return match.replace(/(\w+)/g, '*$1*');
});

document.body.textContent = result;
```

**Explanation**:

The expression `/(\[(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*\])/` will match each bracket group in your case by utilizing an alternation:

```
(            # Capturing group
\[           # Opening bracket
(?:          # Non-capturing group
\[[^\]]*\]   # Match nested brackets that don't contain other brackets
|            # Alternation.. or:
[^\[\]]*     # Match non-bracket characters
)*           # Close the non-capturing group and match it zero or more times
\]           # Closing bracket
)            # Close the capturing group
```

Then in the replace callback, each word is wrapped with the italics:

```
match.replace(/(\w+)/g, '*$1*');
```

Comment: But doesn't this also leave `argumentName` unitalicized?

Comment: @torazaburo No, based on the demo snippet that I provided above, it would return: `[*test1*] test2 ([[*readonly* ][*optionality* ][*argumentType* ]*argumentName*[ = *defaultValue*]]...) [*test3*] test4`.

Comment: Had to replace the inner replace with `([^\[\]]+)` instead of `(\w+)` but otherwise worked great.  Thanks.

Comment: @CoryG Oh, okay, I thought you just wanted words. I'm glad to hear that worked though!

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon, this does not work for [nested brackets](https://jsfiddle.net/lecoder/9oox6cs2/).

Comment: @CoryG I only took brackets nested twice into consideration based on the input you provided. How deeply are the brackets going to be nested?

Comment: Indefinitely nested.